# How to do this regular expression?

Tags: regex

I have something like

"Heading 1    blablabla"

I want to extract the style to have "Heading 1" only
the format is
style + tab + text
I want to get only the style

I've tried (.*)\t(\s.*)$

but it didnt get what i wanted

Comment: addded what ive tried in the question.
You should help for a beginner in regex.
i'm not saying come and do this project folks !!!

Comment: And what happened when you tried the regex above?

Comment: I get some styles as i wanted but It's not reliable, it gets a lot of wrong texts with it.

Comment: Ah yes, I can view your screen now, and I can see **exactly** what unexpected output was generated. Oh, wait.......

Comment: Read the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq : help is for people having problem **with code**, you provide nothing but ask some to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the style only if the string starts with style

```
^(.+?)\t
```

The result is in `$1`

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've done it using -- for any one can make use of it

(?-s)(\S+)[ \s\t]+(.+)

Thanks for your great support